# Any idea why jvm options are prefixed with -XX:?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

Wondering what is the history behind choosing -XX: as prefix for jvm options

Comment: `-X` appears to just have been chosen to represent non standard options, q.v. the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Comment: I dunno... maybe to make the language seem more friendly to women engineers (as opposed to -XY:)?  Or maybe it was their 20th choice of option name?

Comment: `-X` optional but reasonably standard `-XX` highly optional and can changed between versions.

Answer (score 3):

From the **JRockit JVM** [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/intro.htm):

> The nonstandard command-line options of JRockit JVM are divided into
>   two groups:
>
> **-X command-line options**, *which are the most commonly used nonstandard options.*
>
> You can use the -X command-line options to change the behavior of the JRockit JVM to suit the needs of different Java applications. These options do not work on other JVMs (conversely, the nonstandard options used by other JVMs do not work with the JRockit JVM).
>
> **-XX command-line options**, *which are often experimental options that have specific system requirements for their implementation*
>
> To implement some of the options, specific system requirements must be met, otherwise, the particular option does not work. Oracle recommends that you use these options only if you have a thorough understanding of your system. Improper usage of these options can affect the stability or performance of your system.

Comment: thanks. i was wondering how did they arrive at -X/-XX and not -O (Option) or other letters.

Comment: I don't think there would be any particular reason for this.

Comment: @Sundar possibly e**X**perimental